# signed_in? function not working in Chapter 8-9 of Rails Tutorial (Hartl)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have one rspec test failing.

```
  1) User pages edit with valid information should have link "Sign out", {:href=>"/signout"}
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path)   }
   expected #has_link?("Sign out", {:href=>"/signout"}) to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:80:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The test looks to see if a 'Sign out' link is present in the header after signing in. The code works in a browser but not in rspec. The spec in question is aligned with the Hartl tutorial:

```
describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  ...

  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

    ...

    describe "with valid information" do 
        let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
        let(:new_email) { "new@example.com"}
        before do
            fill_in "Name",         with: new_name
            fill_in "Email",        with: new_email
            fill_in "Password",     with: user.password
            fill_in "Confirm Password",     with: user.password
            click_button "Save changes"
        end

        it { should have_title(new_name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success')    }
        it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path)   }
        specify { expect(user.reload.name).to   eq new_name     }
        specify { expect(user.reload.email).to  eq new_email    }
    end
  end
end
```

The following code is the header template being tested (also follows the Hartl Rails tutorial). I've run some tests (using `puts`) and found out that after logging in, the `signed_in?` function is returning false to rspec (while returning true when tested in the browser).

```
        <% if signed_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
          <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
        <% end %>
```

It appears this is a problem with rspec and I haven't been able to figure out what to do to remedy.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where in your RSpec example do you log in?

Comment: **Deleted comments; see answer** Summary: `sign_in user` doesn't get added until Section 9.2.1, in Listing 9.13. I am at the end of Section 9.1, where the tests are supposed to pass based on the code in Listing 9.9, which excludes `sign_in user` (in the `before` block under `describe "edit"`)

Comment: Actually, the book was right as originally written. The tests pass until the before filter is added in [Listing 9.12](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-authorize_before_filter), and the book explicitly identifies the problem and fixes it in [Listing 9.13](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-edit_update_tests_with_signin).

Comment: Answer updated to reflect (hopefully) final resolution after exchange with MHartl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: The original version of this answer focused on Listing 9.1, which turned out to have been correct as is and has since been reverted to its current state with no `sign_in user` due to [other problems the removal caused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860783/rails-tutorial-chapter-9-1-1-sign-in-unrecognised?lq=1). However, the issue with Listing 9.9 noted in the OP's summary comment was a bona fide problem and the fix to add `sign_in user` to that listing remains.

This does appear to have been a bug in the [Rails 4 tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=4.0), which dropped the `sign_in(user)` line from the `before` block in listing 9.9 that was present in the previous version. It has since been corrected.

Comment: Actually, the book was right as originally written. The tests pass until the before filter is added in [Listing 9.12](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-authorize_before_filter), and the book explicitly identifies the problem and fixes it in [Listing 9.13](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-edit_update_tests_with_signin).

Comment: @MHartl Ok, sorry I missed that. I'll update the answer and update the answer to the linked question as well after I've confirmed you've restored the book to the previous state.

Comment: See updated answer which reflects that the OP was right about 9.9 and MHartl was right about 9.1.