# Rails Tutorial chapter 9.1.1 sign_in unrecognised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm working through Michael Hartl's tutorial.

I've just introduced these tests to `user_pages_spec.rb`

```
describe "edit" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    sign_in user
    visit edit_user_path(user)
  end

  describe "page" do
    it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
    it { should have_title("Edit user") }
    it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
  end

  describe "with invalid information" do
    before { click_button "Save changes" }

    it { should have_content('error') }
  end
end
```

My `sessions_helper.rb` file is:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user= user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user=user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

When I run the tests, all 4 fail with error messages along the lines of:

```
1) User pages edit page 
   Failure/Error: sign_in user
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4::Nested_1:0x007fcd57928138>
   # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:90:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How should I get the user pages specs to pick up the sign_in function from sessions_helper? users_controller can use it; it's just the test files that I've done wrong.

I tried including SessionsHelper explicitly and it didn't help.

Comment: Actually, the book was right as originally written. The tests pass until the before filter is added in [Listing 9.12](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-authorize_before_filter), and the book explicitly identifies the problem and fixes it in [Listing 9.13](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-edit_update_tests_with_signin). 

I should have been more careful in updating the book; I've reverted the edit, so now it should work.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this, and thank you for a fantastic resource :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The introduction of the `sign_in user` call in [Listing 9.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-user_edit_specs) was a [recent change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18806971/1008891) that was inconsistent with the fact that this method isn't introduced for use by RSpec until Listing 9.6. It turns out the original version was correct and that call to `sign_in user` has since been removed.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's a big relief