# Sign out link got false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Friends I'm in Michael Hartl Ruby Tutorial 9.1.3(Successful edits).
After completing instruction when i run

```
bundle exec rspec spec /
```

following error occurs..

```
 1) User pages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
   expected #has_link?("Sign out", {:href=>"/signout"}) to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:82:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Finished in 2.71 seconds
63 examples, 1 failure, 3 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:82 # User pages edit with valid information

I'm unable to find error I also upload my code where it says error occured.
User_pages_spec.rb

**User_pages_spec.rb** (complete)

```
  require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end



    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }

        it { should have_link("Sign out") }
        it { should have_title(user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }


      end
      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
   end
   end
  end
describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end

  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { sign_in user }
    before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
      let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
      before do
        fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
        fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
        fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Save changes"
      end

      it { should have_title(new_name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      specify { expect(user.reload.name).to  eq new_name }
      specify { expect(user.reload.email).to eq new_email }
    end

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
      it { should have_title("Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end 
  end
  end

end
```

Comment: Try some basic debugging. 
Start by opening the page in a browser. 
The 'rails console' command will let you run the rspec commands interactively, so you can try and reproduce the issue.

Comment: In browser app is working correctly..
but rspec genrated error which i posted above

Comment: @Json plz explain some basic debugging.
i open Rails console now what?????

Comment: can you paste more view file ? you must have some more user pages

Comment: @Abhinay i edit question and added more pages above.

Comment: @JazibBashir hey can you try removing spaces between" have_link('Sign out',<==here==>href: signout_path "sometimes spaces do raise issues.I have checked everything is alright, but let just try removing spaces first. and please be in front of your computer if you want a quick response.

Comment: @JazibBashir hey I have just found that you didnt added before { sign_in user } to you file right after  "describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }". .so thats the real problem ..

Comment: @JazibBashir please copy this code as it is and paste it into you user_pages_spec.rb

Comment: yes i paste this code it says unexpected end 
i try to check me sytanx of file

Comment: hey dude just added a line of code to your file user_pages_spec.rb, please copy and paste it to your file.and also look at the 1st block of my answer where i have pointed out which line needs to be added.

Comment: yes cause now its working but there might be a  extra "end" needed can you please paste the exact error.

Comment: ok now syntax error is removed ans i paste the sign_in code which you provide the error of sign out is still occur

Comment: `describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user
      visit edit_user_path(user)
    end`

Comment: Yes this should work, are you still getting the sign_out error?

Comment: yes still sign_out error.

Comment: Also, one very important thing is that,you shouldn't be stopping here if this test is not getting passed it has nothing to do with the app development so if you think you are not getting it you can skip it, its not must to have a successful test in order to move ahead.So, you can skip this part and will try to look for an issue

Comment: @Abhinay ok Thanks a lot brother.
now i move toward next exercise.
Thanks a lot

Comment: @JazibBashir and I am sorry if I wasted your time but this is how we resolve issue, people can't guarantee the solution but can try to help you. I dont know where is the problem right now but who knows after finishing up you will be able to resolve it on your own, All the Best. :)

Comment: @Abhinay No Sorry bro.
you r not wasting my time.
you help me to find problem and also spend your important time to find my problem so no sorry.
In this way you also giving me indirect lesson that always help other people.
thanks a lot

Comment: @Abhinay bro all error removed.
user_controller.rb contains some bugs after removing those Rspec working fine.

Comment: @JazibBashir hey I am glad that you resolved the issue,Thats really great. can you tell me where in the controller that bug was ?

Comment: @Abhinay here:

`def create 
   @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys i resolved the error which i discuss above.
I provide you my new updated code because during search i find that a lot of friends having same problems. so compare your code with my new code and hopefully you error also removed.

user_pages_spec.rb

```
 require 'spec_helper'

    describe "User pages" do

      subject { page }

      describe "signup page" do
        before { visit signup_path }

        it { should have_content('Sign up') }
        it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
      end

      describe "signup" do

        before { visit signup_path }

        let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

        describe "with invalid information" do
          it "should not create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
          end
        end



        describe "with valid information" do
          before do
            fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
            fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
            fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
            fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
          end

         describe "after saving the user" do
            before { click_button submit }
            let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }

            it { should have_link('Sign out') }
            it { should have_title(user.name) }
            it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
          end
          it "should create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
       end
       end
      end
    describe "profile page" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before { visit user_path(user) }

        it { should have_content(user.name) }
        it { should have_title(user.name) }
      end

      describe "edit" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before do
          sign_in user
          visit edit_user_path(user)
        end

        describe "with valid information" do
          let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
          let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
          before do
            fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
            fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
            fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
            fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
            click_button "Save changes"
          end

          it { should have_title(new_name) }
          it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
          it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
          specify { expect(user.reload.name).to  eq new_name }
          specify { expect(user.reload.email).to eq new_email }
        end


        describe "page" do
          it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
          it { should have_title("Edit user") }
          it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
        end

         describe "with invalid information" do
          before { click_button "Save changes" }

          it { should have_content('error') }
        end
      end

    end
```

user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create 
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

   def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

_header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
 "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

hope this help!
If you need some more details then ask me.

Thanks
Jazib Bashir

Answer (score 0):

You might find this answer helpful 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18806971/2545197

Does your "edit" in user_pages_spec.rb have this part before  "**describe "with valid information" do**" ?

```
describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user          # <-this line is needed for spec to look for sign_out
      visit edit_user_path(user)
    end
```

Also, you should checkout this line from the right after the code in section 9.9 if you have missed.

"Note that Listing 9.9 adds the **sign_in** method from Listing 9.6 to the before block, which is **required for the** “**Sign out**” **link test to pass**, and also anticipates protecting the edit action from non-signed-in users (Section 9.2.1)."

So,according to this you should have a piece of code in **spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb**
like this:

```
def sign_in(user, options={})
  if options[:no_capybara]
    # Sign in when not using Capybara.
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
  else
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end
end
```

If not then please add it. let me know if it helps or not ?

Comment: yes i have this code before  **describe "with valid indormation" do**
 
 `describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit edit_user_path(user) }`

Comment: and the second code which say in **spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb**
is placed in **spec/support/utilities.rb** according to tutorial.

Comment: Look spec can only check for sign_out if it has signed_in so if this is the error then you might wana add "sign_in user" line to your code,which i have mentioned in my answer also.

Comment: Problem is still same not solved.....

**Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
       expected #has_link?("Sign out", {:href=>"/signout"}) to return true, got false
**

Comment: bro i have this line already and one more thind i deploy my app at localhost it works fine.
but when i run **bundle exec rspec spec /**
it generate error of sign out

Comment: @JazibBashir Failing a test doesn't stops your app from running you should know that, and I am trying to find a problem or solution if you allow me to do so.

Comment: I'm stuck at this part from last 2 days recheck the code 3 to 4 times then also done alot of search but solution not found i'm also unable to understand error because at localhost it works fine

Comment: @JazibBashir hey Can you paste complete content from user_pages_spec.rb cause right now its kind of very hard to determine which part has the problem.

Comment: i edit my question here u can see complete user_pages_spec.rb